# WordPress wp_query featured posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site, and I'm working on a requested feature from my client. The client would like to be able to *feature* certain posts, so that they appear at the top of a list. To make it easy for my client, I created a **featured** category. So when the client wants to feature a post, all they have to do is to add the **featured** category to the post.

Here is my current query to display all posts with the category name of **events**:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => array('events'), 'posts_per_page' => '1' ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $postLink = get_permalink();
            echo '<li class="wp-post">
                      <h5><a href="'.$postLink.'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h5>
                      <p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
                      <div class="wp-post-details">
                          <span class="post-date">'.get_the_date().'</span>
                      </div>
                </li>';
        }
        echo '<li><a href="/categories/events/" class="btn">View All Events</a></li>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
    }
```

I would like to change it, so it would display **events** posts that have the additional category of **featured** first. I have done some searching on Google and here. But as of yet, I have not found a solution that works for my instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the an solution to my issue. I just had to add `if (in_category('feature')) {...` before I echo the HTML.